# Is this database design typical/advantageous

Tags: oracle11g

I know this might be opinion based, but I'm looking at someone's database and I'm curious as to whether or not this is a common technique and what the advantages/disadvantages are, in the spirit of becoming better.

Essentially, they have a set of tables that store monetary transactions by month/year vs one table (as I personally would have made). So it looks like this:

So I'd have made something like:

```
PaymentTable
receiptNumber | Tendered | date 
      001     |    100   | 01/12/2017
      002     |    200   | 02/10/2017
      003     |    300   | 03/7/2017
```

Whereas they made it

```
 Payment0117
    receiptNumber | Tendered | date 
          001     |    100   | 01/12/2017

 Payment0217
    receiptNumber | Tendered | date 
          002     |    200   | 02/10/2017

 Payment0317
    receiptNumber | Tendered | date 
          003     |    300   | 03/7/2017
```

I'll say up front, it's been a pain to work with. They don't have a view set up with all the tables, so if I was looking for receipt 002, I'd have to check every table until I found it. But I'm wondering, are there performance or other advantages to this approach since each table would have fewer rows? They go back to 2006, so there are 10 years*12 months = 120+ of these tables...

Comment: That is terrible!  You could handle this using partitioning functions in oracle.

Comment: I thought it was odd/bad, but I thought maybe I just didn't have the experience to realize if it was a good thing.

Comment: What kind of database is this? Oracle Enterprise, Standard or Express edition? I ask, because this seems like an early attempt at implementing partitioning, and the Express Edition (XE) doesn't have partitioning enabled. Either that, or it's something that was designed yonks ago before partitioning was implemented in the database at all. At the very least, you should expect the accompanying view to be present that union all's the tables together! Personally, I'd go with a single, partitioned table, and then you get the best of both worlds!

Comment: At least, if you were to go about correcting the design to use a partitioned table, you could populate the new table by using partition exchange!

Comment: @Boneist It's 11g enterprise (I picked the wrong tag); but It's been around for awhile so I can't say what version it started as.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg if the tables start from 2006, I would say that it was first developed around then (maybe 2005). Oracle 10g was released in 2004 and Oracle 8i (which is when partitioning was first introduced) was released in 1998, so you'd hope that whoever was developing it did have partitioning available to them. I'm guessing they either didn't know about it, or didn't want to use it for some reason. I would highly recommend changing the design to use a single, partitioned table.

Comment: @Boneist thanks for the insight. I'm not responsible for the database, but I may petition them to change things.

Comment: Good luck with that *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone used table names to store information. That is clearly not conform to a entity-relationship-approach.

A table should represent an entity, like payments, customers etc ... 
The Payment-Month is a property of the payment, and a redundant one as it is contained in the payment date.

I can imagine that was done to get smaller tables and maybe isolate the active accounting month with a lot of writes from the old month, which would be basically read-only. Anyway there are better ways to deal with that.

If the month is a regular argument for reports, that should be properly indexed.

If you have a lot of writes only int the current month, and a lot of reads for only the old month, maybe a buffer-table for writes of the current day/month etc. could make sense or a BI-table to service reporting.